# Why does `count(new stdClass);` return 1?

Tags: php, count

`stdClass` in PHP should be an empty object, but it's `count()` is `1` for some reason. Why?

```
PHP> (array)(new stdClass);
// array(
// 
// )
PHP> empty(new stdClass);
// false
PHP> count(new stdClass);
// 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the [documentation of the count function](https://www.php.net/count), you'll find this section about the return value:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter
> is not an array or *not an object with implemented Countable interface,*
> *1 will be returned*. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is
> NULL, 0 will be returned.

Comment: Good find! Anybody still believes that JS is a surprising language..? :)

Comment: @kolypto But you asked a PHP question.... ?

Comment: @spryno724, sure, just noticing that PHP is also surprising sometimes

Comment: @kolypto If there is one skill I learned from working in JS, it's the ability to scan/read documentation fast and efficient... :P

Comment: @kolypto But why should this be surprising? [See this list](http://3v4l.org/03oXJ) - the output is more or less making sense. You get 0 for `NULL` or something countable and empty and 1 otherwise, because you always have 1 string, 1 boolean, and here: 1 object.

Comment: @kingkero, well, passing an empty object, I expected count() to tell that it's empty. 10 years in PHP, and learning never stops .. :)

Comment: Not true since PHP 7.2: it emits a warning, and from PHP 8, it throws a TypeError.

Answer (score 2):

An object passed to count() needs to implement the Countable interface.

```
echo count(new stdclass()); //outputs 1

class countIt implements Countable{
    public function count(){        
    }
}

echo count(new countIt()); //outputs 0
```

See [Countable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) for more details.